# Plugging monolight into "household" power pack

Tags: power-supply, battery-drain, monolights

I tried to figure out the amperage or the wattage of a monolights, but couldn't find the information. I looked for the Impact and Alien Bees brands, on the manufacturer's website, and on B&H and Amazon for the Impact's.

I also found many "DIY" power packs for monolights, but I don't want to rely on DIY for this kind of thing.

So my question is, let's say I want to occasionally shoot on location and want to plug a 300 W/s monolight in a power pack like the ones we find in the hardware store, would I run into any kind of trouble ?

As an example, I could certainly do all my indoor shoots with something like [Impact Digital 300W/s monolights](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/501613-REG/Impact_VSD_300_VSD300_Digital_Monolight.html) (B&H link), which seems a great kit for the price.

But I'd like to occasionally bring it outside, and I was thinking of a general-purpose power pack like [the Duracell Powerpack Pro 1300](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009YR00MI) (Amazon link).

Comment: Is there a reason you're not looking at [strobe-specific battery packs](http://www.lightingrumours.com/portable-power-guide)? or if you're going for generic cheapie monolights, [one that comes with a battery pack](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Photography-Monolight-Modeling-Rechargeable/dp/B00MP5928Y/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll likely need something with a little higher amp rating than the power pack you have linked. 600W at 110V is only about 5.5A. The peak rating for the 110 VAC outlets is 700w, which translates to about 7A. You probably need about twice to three times that much peak power capacity to tolerate the peak current required by the light at the start of each recycle. You need a power pack that can give you at least 1500-2000W of peak power per light just to work at all when the battery is fully charged.

Answer (score 3):

From FAQ at  http://www.paulcbuff.com/faq.php

Q. What is the average current draw of Paul C. Buff™ flash units?

A: Einstein™ units draw an average current of 5 amps during recycle and AlienBees™ and White Lightning™ flash units draw an average current of 6 amps. This means that if a light were fired every time it recycled, the average current draw would be 5 or 6 amps. At the beginning of each recycle, the lights draw a peak current of about 16 to 18 amps for about 200 milliseconds. This is well tolerated by household circuits and breakers. A typical circuit breaker will tolerate three flash units in normal use. When the lights are idle and not being fired, the current draw is essentially that of the modeling lamp - 1 to 2 amps per unit.